# How do i get the value of selected item from list box in windows phone application using c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the value of selected item from list box and display that message using MessageBox.Show().
This is My XAML code for list Box

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbTodoList" Grid.Row="1"  Width="350" Margin="100,0,0,0">
                <ListBox.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF060000" Offset="0"/>

                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </ListBox.Background>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Listbox" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding salutationName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And c# code is for data binding is

```
List<UserData> info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(e.Result);
List<UserData> items = new List<UserData>();
lbTodoList.Items.Clear();
foreach (UserData item in info)
{
    items.Add(new UserData() { salutationName = item.salutationName });
}
this.lbTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
```

And this is for display the selected item

```
 string text = lbTodoList.SelectedItem.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(text);
```

But problem is instead of display the selected item,it displaying projectName.ClassName

Comment: Use the debugger and inspect the `.SelectedItem` at runtime - you'll discover that it has a property with the desired value. Your current code turns the object itself into a string, not the property value you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to override ToString of UserData to give what you are expecting.

```
public class UserData
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return this.somevalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @TejasJain this is just a simple fix. A better approach would be looking into how binding works and utilising that (MVVM architecture preferred). That way you can use DataTemplates/Converters instead and separate the concerns. Also if this has solved your issue please mark with accepted answer.

Comment: @D Hansen thanks for your information,i'll work on it,what you have said about MVVM.

Comment: @TejasJain a good place to start is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lool8Ut58Xw It gives quite a good introduction to MVVM with a look through development using Test Driven approach.